# How to make onbeforeunload display a message and make conditions for onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm doing a project and I have a task to create an onbeforeunload on a page. I have 2 problem that I still don't get how to correct them:
My project have a page with a lot of input element, and I should create an onbeforeunload when the changes happen. The first thing is that my code for onbeforeunload to display the message that I want didn't work. Here is my code for onbeforeunload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!'
}
```

The second thing is that I have 2 picture that we use as button in the webpage. And everytime I click the pic, onbeforeunload triggered. I want to ask how to write javascript to check if I click those images, the onbeforeunload doesnt trigger anymore?

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
<img src="btn_search" alt="btn_search" width="50" height="30">
<img src="btn_search_2" alt="btn_search" width="50" height="30">
</a>
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ae58vhfw/3/
Thank you very much

Comment: _“The first thing is that my code for onbeforeunload to display the message that I want didn't work.”_ – and that did actually still surprise you, considering the browser support shown here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#browser_compatibility

Comment: _“I want to ask how to write javascript to check if I click those images, the onbeforeunload doesnt trigger anymore?”_ - that is not directly possible. Clicking those images would cause navigation away from the current document, and _that_ is what triggers the event handler. So you would have to un-bind the event handler, when those images get clicked.